# Problem deploying a react app on heroku -- error code 503 on console

Tags: reactjs, heroku, tailwind-css, portfolio

i'm currently uploading my Portfolio, in react, on Heroku, build succeeds but i get this error page with a code 503 in console...
Here is the error :

`GET https://mpj-portfolio-app.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico 503 (Service Unavailable)`

Seems to have something to do with Tailwind and/or the favicon displayed on the tab (which i changed, but then changed back to the original)

I also get these errors in the app logs
`2021-10-21T09:46:40.806231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mpj-portfolio-app.herokuapp.com request_id=bd24e409-699a-4687-8871-4ef1b6023e7c fwd="193.253.212.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

`2021-10-21T09:46:41.308024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mpj-portfolio-app.herokuapp.com request_id=0b1515b1-74a1-49ca-9e79-d7b673ad435b fwd="193.253.212.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Please help ?

Comment: are you using the port from the environment?

Comment: isn't that automatic ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial :

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-aedc28b218ae

Really helpfull, now i just got to figure out how to load Tailwind to my page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).